# Run server and client in the same file - python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using tftpy and need to create a server, then a client to download/upload some file and then I can close the server.

I was thinking on using multiprocessing to accomplish this but I don't know how to close the server gracefully. The last resort will be to use terminate() but perhaps there is a better method (perhaps an easier one not using multiprocessing). I also know about multiprocessing.Event() but I don't know how run_sv() method will keep listening

Here is the code:

```
import multiprocessing
import tftpy

def run_sv():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting sv'
    server = tftpy.TftpServer('./rootf')
    server.listen('0.0.0.0', 69)
    print name, 'Exiting sv'

def run_cl():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting cl'
    client = tftpy.TftpClient('127.0.0.1', 69)
    client.download('aaa.txt', './downf/zzz.txt')
    print name, 'Exiting cl'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = multiprocessing.Process(name='my_sv', target=run_sv)
    worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='my_cl', target=run_cl)

    service.start()
    worker_1.start()
```

The output:

```
my_sv Starting sv
my_cl Starting cl
my_cl Exiting cl
```

and of course it hangs there.

Comment: tried calling .close() on server before the end of run_sv?

Comment: servers do tend to run indefinitely, you should find a way how to shuit it down after the client has done its work

Comment: no close() method. the server starts to listen and doesn't give the "promt" back. Terminating the process pid with terminate() is an alternative but is not graceful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
service.start()
worker_1.start()
worker_1.join()
service.terminate()
```

Comment: Did it hang in the main process at the waiting for the client or for the server that time?

Comment: import tftpy


client = tftpy.TftpClient('192.168.0.42', 69, options={'blksize': 8});client.download('breed.bin','output.bin')                                             TftpException: Invalid options in buffer